# Compartilhar objeto entre dois controllers no angularjs

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-factorys

Estou estudando `AngularJS` e estou tentando fazer um `CRUD` simples, porem não estou conseguindo ter o mesmo objeto da minha listagem para o meu formulário, ou seja, na hora que clicar no botão de editar ir para o formulário preenchido pelo objeto.

Tenho a `Factory` (li sobre compartilhar dados porem só atributo, queria compartilhar o objeto inteiro)

```
app.factory('item', function(){
  return item; 
});
```

Minha lista:

```
 <tbody>
   <tr ng-repeat="item in lista">
      <td>{{item.id}}</td>
      <td>{{item.descricao}}</td>
      <td>{{item.status}}</td>
      <td>{{item.prioridade}}</td>
      <td>{{item.tipo}}</td>
      <td>
         <a class="btn" href="#" ng-click="editItem(item)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
         <a class="btn" href="#" ng-click="deleteItem(item)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a>
      </td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

E meus Controllers

```
app.controller("listCtrl", function($scope, $http, $location, item){
    $scope.itemAux = item;
    $scope.loadData = function(){ ... };
    $scope.deleteItem = function(item){ ... };

    $scope.editItem = function(itemX){
         $scope.itemAux = itemX;
         $location.path('/cadastro');
    };
}

app.controller("formCtrl", function($scope, $http, $location, item){
    $scope.itemAux = item;

    $scope.save = function(){ ... }
    $scope.update = function(){ ... }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008908/angularjs-how-can-i-pass-variables-between-controllers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem algumas maneiras de se obter o resultado que você deseja, como utilizar `$rootScope`, `$broadcast` ou então armazenar os dados no `SessionStorage` ou `LocalStorage`, etc.

Uma das maneiras mais simples é criar um `Service` pra compartilhar os dados entre os dois Controllers, Exemplo:

```js
angular.module('myApp',[]);

angular.module('myApp').factory('myService', function() {
 var valor = {}
 
 function set(data) {
   valor = data;
 }
 function get() {
  return valor;
 }

 return {
  set: set,
  get: get
 }

});
angular.module("myApp")
    .controller("ctrl1", function($scope, myService){
    $scope.pessoa = {id: 1, nome: 'Diego', idade: 23};
    //Atribui um valor ao serviço
    myService.set($scope.pessoa);
});
angular.module("myApp")
    .controller("ctrl2", function($scope, myService){
     //Pega o valor atribuido ao serviço
     $scope.pessoa = myService.get();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl1">
     <h1>Controller 1</h1>
  Atributo: {{pessoa.nome}}!
</div>

<div ng-controller="ctrl2">
  <h1>Controller 2</h1>
  Objeto: {{pessoa}}!
  <br>
  Atributos: {{pessoa.nome}} -- {{pessoa.idade}}!
</div>
</div>
```

Para mais informações recomendo os links:

[Services](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services)

[Factory x Services](http://tableless.com.br/angular-js-service-x-factory/)

Comment: Obrigado, não sabia sobre service, deu certinho. obrigado!